# Friend fuction cannot change the value, Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

Why I cannot change the member value? I already declare it as a friend function in the header file.

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in,const Rational2& r){
    char space;
    in>>r.numerator>>space>>r.denominator;
    return in;
}
```

Then it comes up with a "invalid operands to binary expression".

I have a base class called "Rational", and the derived class called "Rational2", protected inheritance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: You have const& for r, remove const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it, because `r` is `const&`. Just remove `const` qualifier.

Signature should be:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Rational2& r)
```